# Can I move my .MDB database into Office365?

Tags: ms-access, vba, office365

**Can i Move my .MDB database file to the Office365 account (Web access database provided by office365) is it possible?** Or *I have to recreate macro using office365(web Access database)*, Had already googled but cant get Exact logic ?

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer sir,thanks for editing the question I will never do this kind of mistake again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Two very different animals. Besides, AWA are just about being closed down:

[Access Services in SharePoint Roadmap](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Access-Services-in-SharePoint-Roadmap-497fd86b-e982-43c4-8318-81e6d3e711e8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: so how to tackle with this, we have 20 + macros developed for our client?? and they will migrate to office365 soon.

Comment: Good question. There is no direct method. It will be a complete rebuild. Microsoft suggests, as you can see, _PowerApps_, but these are at the present stage severely limited. Some point to [Zoho Creator](https://www.zoho.eu/creator/) as an alternative, but I have zero experience with this.